# "Instant" vs. "instantaneous" 

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *instant* and *instantaneous*? Which is correct in this sentence?

> It had an almost **__** response time.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the fact that manufacturers of instant coffee never call it 'instantaneous coffee' I would say that 'instant' modifies a noun referring to a thing, whereas 'instantaneous' modifies a noun referring to an event. Your example falls in a grey area between the two, because the noun 'time' can refer to either the *duration* before the response occurs or the *event* of the response's occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

They are nearly identical.  *Instantaneous* focuses more on something occurring in an instant or instantly, whereas *instant* simply means "immediately".

However, being that both words necessarily involve time, your sentence would be redundant.  Might I suggest one of the following:

> It had a near zero response time.
>
> It responded (almost) instantly/instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

"Instantaneous" has significantly more immediacy associated with it than "instant".  If you shift them to adverb form, the difference is even more evident. Consider these two sentences:

-- The spark jumped between the two electrodes instantaneously.

-- Upon receiving news of a moose down by the swamp, the hunter set off immediately.

Comment: It would be easier to understand the comparison if the second example used the adverb form of instant rather than immediate.