# "Instantly" vs "instantaneously"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Instant” vs. “instantaneous”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20129/instant-vs-instantaneous)

I know there is a similar question already answered, but I still have doubts. I was doing a word formation FCE exercise where I had to form an adverb from the word *instant* in the following sentence.

> The artists created their own style and use of colours, which is
>   **instantly/instantaneously** recognisable.

Is *instantly* the adverb I should use?

Comment: Perhaps [Difference between instantly and instantaneously](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42168) is the question you looked at; and while it sounds like a duplicate it might not be.  However, the example in the older question  [When should I use instant vs instantaneous](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20129) makes your question a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry if I created a duplicate question; as I pointed out, I had read a similar question (and the attached answers), but I was still in doubt about what to use in the specific sentence I was dealing with.

Comment: @Paola - For my personal experience, I know how difficult is to find similar question on this website. Hence +1 at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "instantly" is more appropriate.  Nobody will misunderstand you if you use "instantaneously", but you will sound like you're trying to talk above your competency and failing.